# Where are WAMP's MySQL "lib" and "include" directories?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, wamp

I have provide the path to MySQL's `lib` and `include` directories as described [in step #10 here](http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html#comment-form).

However, I can't find these directories in my WAMP installation on Windows 7 (32-bits).

I tried to point to the `bin` directory:

```
gem install mysql2 -- 
   '--with-mysql-lib="c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin" 
    --with-mysql-include="c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin"'
```

but it doesn't work:

```
...
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
...
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.xx"'
```

Been searching for a few hours and not seen this variation suggested, so hopefully it will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Change the directory location to point both to the bin directory both dll's are in there.

I.E.:

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\wamp\bin\mysql5.1.xx\bin" --with-mysql-include="c:\wamp\bin\mysql5.1.xx\bin"'
```

that should work. just change the version file with the correct version.